# How to get labels for ILSVRC2012 Classification Task

Tags: imagenet

The ILSVRC 2012 small classification dataset is not separated by folder and don't have a labels file. How get the labels for the training set?

I tried on nonpub downloads page but does not exist anymore, and i tried by the filenames but their don't have the synset id on it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This question does not appear to be about programming

Comment: https://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2012/browse-synsets.php

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue today following [this](https://calebrob.com/ml/imagenet/ilsvrc2012/2018/10/22/imagenet-benchmarking.html) tutorial on reproducing ImageNet Validation results. I think I've found an answer, even if partial

In the article they point out to [this link](https://academictorrents.com/details/5d6d0df7ed81efd49ca99ea4737e0ae5e3a5f2e5) to get the validation set for object detection. I downloaded it and had the same issue as yourself, it only contains images without labels. What I've found is that this same website had [this other link](https://academictorrents.com/details/dfa9ab2528ce76b907047aa8cf8fc792852facb9) for the bounding boxes. I've downloaded it and alongside with the bboxes it comes with the proper class for each image

Hope this helps!